# Is it clear from this...?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Holly: He's been pressuring me to see them for a long time.

He: Brad (Holly's brother)

Them: Holly's parents

1) Is it clear from Holly's statement that it's Brad who wants her to see their parents?

- and if not, would I have to change the sentence even though the context makes it clear?

2) Does the sentence say anything about whether Holly has seen her parents through the period where Brad has been pressuring her to see them (maybe he just wants her to visit them more often)?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: The wording "Is it clear from this…?" could apply to almost anything.

The form "Speaker: He's been pressuring me to see them for a long time." looks like part of a play script.

1) Is it clear from this that it's "he" who wants the speaker to see "them"?

"if not," how could you not need to change the sentence? What else would have been the point?

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not clear who "them" is in this scenario. In order to make it clearer, you could change "them" to "him/her" if it is an individual so that it reads:

> "Speaker: He's been pressuring me to see him for a long time."

However, without proper context from the previous sentence we are not sure if "them" is a single person or multiple people.

2) Using context clues, we can assume that the speaker hasn't seen "them" for a long time, as they have been being pressured to see them for a long time.